# How to write a Cypher query with a condition on one of relationship properties in Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

#### My question:

I am new to Neo4j and trying to create a query listing nodes and relationships into a graph with keyword as **"id=0001"** as below:

**(a) - [id:'0001', ref_id:null] -> (b) - [id:'0002', ref_id:'0001'] -> (c) - [id:'0003', ref_id:'0002'] -> (d)**

Start Node will be (a) since it has relationship with id=0001

But the database also exists relationships which I don't want:

**(a) - [id:'2001', ref_id:null] -> (b) - [id:'2002', ref_id:'2001'] -> (c)

(a) - [id:'3001', ref_id:null] -> (b) - [id:'3002', ref_id:'3001'] -> (c)**

The result should only includes:

(a)-[0001]-(b)-[0002, 0001]-(c)-[0003,0002]-(d)

#### Below are what I was thinking before write question:

I know how to create this query in SQL database like Oracle and MySQL, I can use query with "where" condition. For example:

```
Select * 
from table_a parent, (select * from table_a) child 
where child.ref_id = parent.id
```

Then I can loop the result set in Java to find all relationships. But this is stupid.

I think the query should looks like:

```
Match (n)-[r:RELTYPE]->(m) WHERE {some conditions at here} RETURN n,r,m
```

Please help me, thank you!

Yufan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use named relationships and filter in `WHERE` clause:

```
match p = (a)-[r1:TYPE]->(b)-[r2:TYPE2]->(c)
where r1.id='0001' and r2.id='0002' and r2.ref_id='0001'
return p
```

Please note that properties having null value are not allowed in Neo4j. So the first relationship won't have a `ref_id`.

For the above notation is a shortcut by putting the conditions into the `match`:

```
match p = (a)-[r1:TYPE {id:'0001'}]->(b)-[r2:TYPE2 {id:'0002', ref_id:'0001'}]->(c)
return p
```

*On a side note*: I'm not sure if the way you're using `id` and `ref_id` in relationship properties is a good way to model your data. Maybe you can use more verbose relationship types - however without understanding the domain it's not really possible to give a good advice here.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for helping. Is it possible to find all related objects only input r1.id='0001'? My model have "user" and "messages", I need to link all user's messages together, so I put messages into relationships and user into nodes, is there any better to model this relationships?

Comment: Since a message is something having an identity you should model them as node and connect them via FROM and TO relationships to sender and recipient. If messages are modeled as nodes they are referenceable so two messages can have e.g. a REPLY_TO relationship. This kind of modelling is way more "graphy" than using id references on relationships. Grab a pdf copy of http://www.graphdatabases.com and read through it.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you again for your very helpful reply. I decided to loop all messages from the result set in Java. There is a reason why I did not put messages as nodes. Because there will be different kinds of nodes in same graph database hence there will not having direct relationships from a user to another user(It will have new relationships like a user to a message node to another user).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this Cypher query to find all neighbor with depth = 3.

```
MATCH (a)-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c)-[r3]-(n) 
WHERE n.APPLE_ID='12345' 
RETURN distinct n, distinct r3
```

Thanks